# Error in "<init>()" for android 2.3.3

Tags: android, init

I have an app that works fine without errors in emulators for Android:

- 2.1
- 2.3.3
- 4.03

It also works fine on my 4.03 Touchpad.

However, the Google Play crash error report says:

Error in main_menu.< init >() 26 reports

(note: there are no spaces between the open/close carrots and 'init', but stackoverflow wouldn't let me do that)

A user emailed me and said it happens with his Samsung galaxy S running 2.3.3, and says it crashes on startup without any errors.

This is the snippet for main_menu.java. I honestly don't know where to start on this . . . any ideas?

ps - I'm a weak Android programmer, so be kind and go into details . . .

```
package robot_calc.android;

import sor.robotics.calculators.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class main_menu extends Activity
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
  {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    Button bOhm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOhmClick);
    Button bLed = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLedClick);
    Button bBat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnBatClick);
    Button bEnc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEncClick);

    bOhm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main_menu.this, ohm_calculator.class);
        startActivity(i);
      } 
    });
    bLed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main_menu.this, led_calculator.class);
        startActivity(i);
      } 
    });
    bBat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main_menu.this, battery_calculator.class);
        startActivity(i);
      } 
    });
    bEnc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Intent i = new Intent(main_menu.this, encoder_calculator.class);
        startActivity(i);
      } 
    });
  }
}
```

### The stack trace from Google Play:

```
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The import sor.robotics.calculators.R cannot be resolved
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable
R cannot be resolved to a variable

at robot_calc.android.main_menu.<init>(main_menu.java:8)
at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Mind posting the full stack trace?

Comment: My code is not throwing any exceptions to my knowledge. Is it then still possible to get a stacktrace? (I'm a noob to Java, I apologize)

I added this to my code, and ran debugger:
  try{
      //my code
  catch(Exception ex){
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }

But nothing different came up. It works 100% perfect without error in my emulator. (Perhaps I'm not doing this right?)

Comment: Doesn't google play provide the stack trace? I recall one of my apps crashing and I could see the trace in the dev console. Understandably, if your code is running fine on the emulator, you won't get a stack trace.

Comment: Ah! I didn't know Google Play showed the trace lol. Ok, found that, and all of the errors seem to have the same theme:
"The import sor.robotics.calculators.R cannot be resolved
R cannot be resolved to a variable"

How should I modify my code to fix this?

Comment: Take out the `import sor.robotics.calculators.R;` `R` should never have to be imported. However I don't see why Google play would be throwing that up. Stack traces contain `Exception`s, not compile time errors.

Comment: Well, removing that line breaks all my code that uses R (shown in the code pasted above). Does the order that I do my imports matter? I have another very similar app that doesn't get any errors that also has the same basic import. But the order isn't the same.
import sor.axon.datasheets.R; and my buttons look like this ImageView bAxon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnAxnClick);

Comment: `R` should not need to be imported so I can't say why your code isn't working without the import, try cleaning your your project and post the full stack trace that Play gives you.

Comment: R does need to be imported... But it should be your package's R, and not the default R. I suspect this is a faulty or corrupted install, resulting in the resources being invalid.

Comment: @Dororo `R` does not need an explicit import since it should be part of the package. But I do agree about the possibly corrupted install.

Comment: I've always needed to import R for my own package when dealing with resources. This has never caused a problem. @societyofrobots if everyone is reporting this, then I think you may have a corrupt build up, which can (and does) happen when building with Eclipse occasionally. I would recommend doing a full clean and build then reposting it on the marketplace. If it's an isolated case, then I would bet a faulty download or a rooted phone which cannot load applications properly.

Comment: importing the right R is ok. However the R imported here does not match his package name.
Do you have any library projects referenced in your project? If yes, is it correct that you import this project's R?

Comment: Turns out it was a corrupted build. I changed the package name in the AndroidManifest file, and that didn't propagate properly. Eclipse didn't show me any errors and happily built it for me. I should have gone to Android Tools => Rename Application Package. Sigh, that took 5 hours to figure out . . . thanks everyone!